# Why can some people close others answer

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, questions, markdown

So , it has been quite some time i started using this platform , and I was just looking at few questions that showed " this question is not accepting any answers " which means it must have been downvoted and closed,  right ??

Now my question is if any user feels that the given question is not good or precise or too direct for them then they can leave it , why to stop others  from answering if the other person wants to .

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797397/sufficient-statistic-function-for-fx-theta-x-2-0-theta-leq-x

So one should restrain his choice only to oneself , if you don't like a question then comment that , but altogether closing the question doesn't seem to be fair ..

Just a thought , maybe  I am thinking only from one dimension , buti really want your views on this thing .

Comment: Our views don't matter: this is how the SE platform works. When a question is ambiguous, answering it only creates confusion and error.  Ultimately, this curation is what makes SE sites superior to other Q&A platforms.  Please read through our [help pages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how to ask good questions and how to get closed questions reopened.

Comment: And with no reason , I have two downvotes , thank you !

Comment: There doesn't have to be a reason: on this Meta site, downvotes indicate agreement or disagreement with proposals rather than an assessment of the quality or clarity of a question or answer.  It really is time to learn how CV works, rather than complaining about it!

Comment: The good news about SE can be that well-informed people willingly give their time to write good answers that you can read, for free. The bad news about SE -- if your wishes or expectations are different -- might be that it is not a help line in which there is entitlement to answers and that reputation carries privileges and responsibilities to maintain standards, which can mean downvoting or closing questions. You've benefitted too, as your reputation is well above 1 and you've received answers to questions and upvotes.

Comment: @simran SE is attempting an optimization strategy for increasing quality. It doesn't maximize everything good about Q&A, nor does it minimize everything bad about Q&A. But it does certain things quite well. You should use it for the things that it does well at, and use other resources for the things it does poorly at.

Answer (score 9):

Your most recently [closed question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/534272/176202) has been closed for being a self-study question that is lacking:

- The [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag. The idea is that you read the wiki when you add it to your post so that...
- ...you are aware that self-study questions *are* in fact allowed! As long as you include what you have tried and where you are stuck.

We encourage new users to **read the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)**. Common reasons for closure are actually covered in the tour:

[image: CVtour]

For what it's worth, you even get a badge for going through the tour completely.

Neither closing a question, nor downvoting is a statement of "I don't like this". Instead, it is as @whuber mentions in the comments, a way of curating the site. In fact, you are free to edit your question, delete it, ask another, as many times as you want.